# Header weekly by date column in json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

sorry about clumsily question,
i'm not really sure it possible, i read data from Mysql db correctly with json 
and display them into element that is not table
in database i have some appointment date that will be display to client group by weekly and have next link to other week.
there is some code,i's sorry about lot of that.
here is html code :

```
<div class="timesviewport">
    <div class="selector">
        <div class="title-collection" style="">
           <!--time add here-->
        </div>
        <div class="selector-header">
            <div class="header-title-collection" style="">
              <!--date add here--> 
            </div>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="prevlink">
                   <div class="nextprevloading"></div>
                       <a class="prevweeklink" href="#" rel="nofollow">before</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nextlink">
                   <div class="nextprevloading"></div>
                       <a class="nextweeklink" href="#" rel="nofollow" data-test="search-next-week-link">next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                    
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is javascript

```
function getresDetails(id)
{
    var new_res_date = '' ;
    var new_res_time = '' ;

    new_res_time += '<div class="title"><div class="title-row-collection">';

    daily = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
    j=0;

    var id_val = id.value;
    var url = "table.php?id="+id_val;

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        new_res_date +='<div class="header-title"><div class="header-title-date-collection" id="adddate">';
        new_res_time += '<div class="title-row"><div class="title-row-date-collection">' ;

        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            if(i==0)
            {
                new_res_date += '<div class="header-title-date"><div class="header-title-date-name">'+daily[j%7]+ '</div><div class="header-title-date-value">'+json[i].res_date+ '</div></div>';
                new_res_time +=  '<div class="title-row-date"><div class="appointment-collection"><div class="appointment-collection-first"><div><a class="appointment-time" href="#">'+json[i].res_time+'</a></div>' ;
                //alert("first :" +i);
                j++;
            }
            else if (i>0 && json[i-1].res_date==json[i].res_date)
            {
                new_res_time += '<div><a class="appointment-time" href="#">'+json[i].res_time+ '</a></div>';
                //alert("second :" +i);
            }
            else
            {
                new_res_date +=  '<div class="header-title-date"><div class="header-title-date-name">'+daily[j%7]+ '</div><div class="header-title-date-value">'+json[i].res_date+ '</div></div>';
                new_res_time +=  '</div></div></div><div class="title-row-date"><div class="appointment-collection"><div class="appointment-collection-first"><div><a class="appointment-time" href="#">'+json[i].res_time+ '</a></div>';
                //alert("third :" +i);
                j++;
            }
        });
        j=0;
        new_res_date += '</div></div>' ;
        new_res_time += '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>' ;

        $(new_res_time).appendTo(".title-row-collection");
        $(new_res_date).appendTo(".header-title-collection");
    });
}
```

and other page that read data from databse is here

`table.php` :

```
<?php

include 'configure.php';

$doc_id = $_GET["id"];

$qr = "SELECT `res_date`,`res_time` FROM `reserve_tbl` WHERE `doc_id` = '".$doc_id."'";

$res= mysql_query($qr);


$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $res_arr[$i]["res_date"] = $row["res_date"]; 
    $res_arr[$i]["res_time"] = $row["res_time"];
    $i++;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res_arr);
?>
```

and 
`profinf.php`:

```
<?php

include 'configure.php';

$doc_id = $_GET["id"];

$qr = "SELECT * FROM `doc_tbl`  WHERE `doc_id`  = '".$doc_id."'";

$res= mysql_query($qr)  or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br />In Query: " . $qr);;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $doc_arr[$i]["doc_name"] = $row["doc_name"];
    $doc_arr[$i]["doc_family"] = $row["doc_family"];
    $doc_arr[$i]["doc_grade"] = $row["doc_grade"];
    $doc_arr[$i]["doc_specialy"]= $row["doc_specialy"];
    $doc_arr[$i]["doc_adress"] = $row["doc_adress"];
    $i++;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($doc_arr);
?>
```

finaly here is connection `configure.php`

```
<?php
$cfg_server = "localhost";
$cfg_database   = "db_name";
$cfg_username   = "root";
$cfg_password   = "";

$conn = mysql_connect($cfg_server, $cfg_username, $cfg_password);
if($conn)
{
    if (!mysql_select_db($cfg_database))
    {
        die('Could not select Database: '.mysql_error());
    }
}
if (!$conn)
{
    die('Could not connect to Database: '.mysql_error());
}
?>
```

anybody have same the problem before?i need to display date column group by weekly element that is not table, if i use table is easier? but i don't know how can display column weekly group in table!can i group by data by SQL query?

thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding you need to do a weekly view of some data?

Comment: _“Really no one?!”_ – TL;DR maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySql has a Week function.

if you change your query to :-

```
SELECT `res_date`,`res_time`, WEEK(res_date) AS `res_week` FROM `reserve_tbl` WHERE `doc_id` = '".$doc_id."'";
```

You will be able to use the `res_week` field to track each record by week number and therefore show previous and next weeks